# XSLT: How to reuse a template within another template

Tags: xml, xslt

If I have a template as follows, which is used to create a button:

```
<xsl:template match="button" name="button">
  <a class="button" href="{@href}">
    <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
  </a>
</xsl:template>
```

I want to be able to use that button in another template, like this:

```
<xsl:template match="createForm">
  ...
  <button name="Create" href="/create"/>
</xsl:template>
```

However, this will just output the button tag as-is. I would like it to be processed through the existing button template. How can this be achieved?

--

**Thanks David M for your answer**. Here is what I have now for the button template:

```
<xsl:template match="button" name="button">
  <xsl:param name="name" select="@name"/>
  <xsl:param name="href" select="@href"/>
  <a class="button" href="{$href}">
    <xsl:value-of select="$name"/>
  </a>
</xsl:template>
```

The createForm template now looks like this:

```
<xsl:template match="createForm">
  ...
  <xsl:call-template name="button">
    <xsl:with-param name="name" select="'Create'"/>
  </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Not sure about the title of this one... Care to explain?

Comment: Yeah it's not really an appropriate title. Couldn't think of a title. Suggestion?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using this (off the top of my head):

```
<xsl:call-template name="button">
    <xsl:with-param name="name" value="Create" />
    <xsl:with-param name="href" value="/create" />
</xsl:call-template>
```

You'll also need to declare your two parameters within your button template using `<xsl:param ...>`.

Comment: note that the default value is related to the context node - those aren't string literals. In the given example, I would use value="@name" and value="@href" respectively.

Comment: @Marc - but the "context node" you refer to was within the XSLT, not the file being processed ... this was just the wrong approach to calling a template wasn't it?

Answer (score 2):

As long as you use `<xsl:include ... />` or `<xsl:import ... />`, you should be able to use either of:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="button"/> <!-- or your own selector -->
```

(which assumes there are button elements under the context node)

or `<xsl:call-template/>` using the name